# Subscriptions and content for iTunesConnect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm confused on how subscriptions work. Let's say I have add a subscription for for my magazine. It's for a whole year. My magazine is released on a quarterly basis. Now this is what confuses me:

Does the actual content, ie the magazine issues, have to be created as a Non-Consumable item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you'd need a separate non-consumable item for each issue is if you wanted to offer individual issues for sale outside of a subscription.  Presumably you'd hide these individual sale-items from subscribers since they have no need to purchase them.

Once the user has a subscription it becomes your responsibility to verify that the subscription is current and to download your new content to the app.  If you save the transaction receipt from the subscription purchase then you can resubmit that to Apple each quarter and validate it prior to downloading content to the app.

Comment: OK thank you Tom. We will only sell our content through a subscription so that settles that then.